# SELECT to find end station for every station from data consisting of pairs of connected stations

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have data consisting of pairs of connected stations (from a to b), for example like this but only columns a b:

```
a b    route stop_no
O U    1     1
A B    2     1
B C    2     2
X Y    3     1
C D    2     3
```

As represented in example,

1. all routes are one direction routes and from one station you can get only to one end station.
2. Stops within one route are ordered (if you could filter out only one route, stop_no would be always ordered), but routes are mixed in between each other (pair of stations of one route could be in between pairs of stations of other routes).

Is there a way to write SELECT to get result like this, where third column represents end station?

```
a b end_station
O U U
A B D
X Y Y
B C D
C D D
```

If there is no way to write "simple" SELECT, is there any solution? I need to use alghoritm like this within INSERT INTO TABLE stored procedure. I work with SQL Developer 20.

Thanks.

Comment: What is "like  this", why ACD is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple hierarchical (`connect by`) query can do this:

```
select  connect_by_root(a) as a, connect_by_root(b) as b, b as end_station
from    routes_table
where   connect_by_isleaf = 1
connect by a = prior b
;
```

We select only the leaf rows (`connect_by_isleaf = 1) for each starting row. The output shows the` a`and`b `from the "root" row (`connect_by_root`) and the` b` value from the leaf row (terminus station).

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple *recursive with* query

```
WITH  rec (end_id, a,b, lvl) AS (
    SELECT  b as end_id,
            a, b,
            0 AS lvl
    FROM tab where b in (select b from tab minus select a from tab)
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT  rec.end_id end_id, 
            tab.a, tab.b,
            lvl + 1
    FROM tab 
    JOIN rec
    ON tab.b  = rec.a
)
 
SELECT 
    a,b, end_id, lvl
FROM rec 
;


A B END_ID     LVL
- - - ----------
O U U          0
X Y Y          0
C D D          0
B C D          1
A B D          2
```

Start at the botton (your *end* points). You get them with

```
(select b from tab minus select a from tab)
```

and go *recursive* back while keeping the `end_id` (aka end station) point.

The `level` show the distance between the `b` and `end_id`

**Alternatively** use the former Oracle *hierarchical query* with the same approach (and result)

```
select a, b, connect_by_root(b) as end_id
from tab
start with b in (select b from tab minus select a from tab)
connect by b = prior a
;

A B END_ID
- - ------
C D D
B C D
A B D
O U U
X Y Y
```